# ZBrush with insert brush mesh won't import into Blender

Tags: import

I'm creating in ZBrush and then exporting as obj and importing into Blender for rigging and weighting.  I can't seem to import mesh that has ZBrush insert brush on it.  Blender pops up a window full of errors.  Is there a way to do this?  Something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi, it seems you should add more information, like what does it mean "mesh that has ZBrush insert brush on it" ? Which errors does Blender show ? What import settings do you use ? A link to [uploaded](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) version of the file could also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by clicking the "make polymesh 3d" button and then exporting from there. It should then import just fine into blender.